# Doing a special sort in MySQL, 3 random top scores, than all random

Tags: mysql, sql, random, subquery, union

I want to have a MYSQL statement which takes three scores which are either 4 or 5 and sorts them at the top of my query results. Then, the results should be all random after that, but not repeat the top 2.

I've tried doing a UNION ALL statement with the same random number seed, but the NOT IN statement doesn't like having a "limit" in the subquery. I think I need to do some type of transform on the subquery after the NOT IN statement. Thoughts?

```
select * from (select * from mydb.mytable where score in (5,4) order by rand(3423)     limit 3) toplist1
UNION all
select *
from mydb.mytable allothers
where allothers.reviewid NOT IN (select reviewid from mydb.mytable where score in (5,4)     order by rand(3423) limit 3)
order by rand(45423)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe...

```
Select * from (
  select A.*, 0 as OrderVal
  from mydb.mytable A
  where score in (5,4) 
  order by rand(3423)     
  limit 3) A
UNION all (
  select *, 1 as orderval
  from mydb.mytable allothers
  where allothers.reviewid NOT IN (
   select reviewid 
   from mydb.mytable 
   where score in (5,4)     
   order by rand(3423) 
   limit 3)
  ) B
ORDER BY orderVal, rand(3423)
```

Comment: The `order by` in your subselects are not necessary. Also, this query suffers from the same issue the op's does. The `NOT IN` may not necessarily return the same random 3 results as the first select.

Comment: Odd.  I thought since we wanted a random 3 from each set they would be. and then the final results to be random within the orderval.. but I could be wrong. wouldn't be the first time, and won't be the last. as far as the not in... wasn't an issue the OP asked to have fixed perhaps that's what's desired.. *shrug*

Comment: hmm. Actually, you might be right. I didn't really think about the fact that we would be ordering in the same way. Ordered randomness. From microsoft:  For a specified seed value, the result returned is always the same

Comment: This sorta works. The entries are all there and sorted but the top 3 are duplicated.

Comment: if mydb.mytable contains multiple entries for 5,4 that "look the same" it's possible they could be duplicated.  If however there are no duplicates then I"m curious as to How it could be generating duplicates....  Don't know if a distinct would help here or not if data is duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing a union all, use a Union. `Union All` pulls back all the information from all of your selects. `Union` filters out the duplicate records. Essentially it is like putting your whole query into a subselect and then using a group by or a distinct.

```
select *
from mydb.mytable toplist1
where score in (5,4) order by rand(3423)
limit 3 

UNION

select *
from mydb.mytable allothers
order by rand(45423)
```

This query will pull back your three random records. Then, it will pull back all the records in the table and filter the original three records out of that result. Then, everything is returned as one table.

Comment: This works, but strangely I still needed to pass subselects in order to get the ordering to work.

Comment: @tomriecken I'm not sure what 'pass subselects' means. The order by should work as is. Can you detail what you did to make this work?